# Major Chess 960 tournaments?

Tags: tournament, chess-variants, chess960

Does anyone have any information about upcoming [Chess 960](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess960) tournaments at the top level (i.e. GMs and IMs)? Even links to/information about past, major tournaments would be appreciated. I recently learned about Chess 960, and find it quite fascinating. I am also of the opinion that it would be more interesting to follow/study than regular chess early on in the game (since opening theory in regular chess goes as far as 25-30 moves in some openings), and beautiful novelties such as [Aronian-Anand, 2013](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1704763) can be prepared at home.

Comment: I can't figure out what 960 has to do with the game to which you linked, but that game was indeed eyebrow-lifting.  Anand offered a bishop, a knight, and a rook, some for multiple moves.

Comment: I don't think anyone objects to 'beautiful novelties prepared at home'.  The issue is the draw rate at the master level.

Comment: I'm not objecting to home prep. The beauty still remains. And I linked the wiki page about chess 960, because I felt that it would be wrong to assume that everyone here would know what it is.

Comment: To all those who voted to close this, note that chess 960 is the most popular chess variant, and is played by many super GMs, so I don't think my request to obtain a resource to look at these games is unreasonable.

Comment: This is a Q&A site.  After a few months, the proper answers for your post would be in the past.  That makes it "too localized" for this site.  Good sentiment, wrong site.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I would disagree that the proper answers would be in the past after a while. I haven't set any sort of time period. I'm just looking for upcoming tournaments. If I posed the same question about regular chess, I'd get answers like the FIDE Grand Prix, or the European Championship, amongst other things, as they are tournaments that happen on a regular basis. Moreover, I'm not just asking about upcoming tournaments, but also about past tournaments. Surely that wouldn't make it "too localized".

Comment: Don't let you fall into the "today's chess has too much theory" trap! You can reach 2300+ FIDE level studying regular chess and knowing little to no theory. Some strategical themes are specific to standard chess, so you won't learn as much from 960 Chess. If you want less "theory-charged" games, have a look at classical games

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Present 
[2nd Chess 960 World cup](http://www.iccf-webchess.com/Message.aspx?message=501) to be played on Feb 15th,2013. The winner qualified as World Championship Candidates.
[This link](http://www.iccf-webchess.com/Message.aspx?message=439) shows the schedule for the 3rd and 4th Chess 960 World cup.

[Chess960 news](http://www.uschess.org/index.php?searchword=chess960&option=com_search&searchphrase=all&Itemid=5) from the US CHess federation website. Talks of past and current events.

Past 
Here is information about a past international [FiNet Chess 960 open](http://www.chessbase.com/newsdetail.asp?newsid=5630) which was won by Alexander Grischuk of Russia.

[Chess960 World Rapid Chess Championship](http://chesstigers.de/ccm10_index_news.php?id=1782&rubrik=6&lang=1&kat=2&PHPSESSID=c16f2a95dc95c0bb4a828ebaf2347918)
Nakamura simply won the first three games to become new World Champion – in a very convincing manner. Link also has games information and pictures as well. [This](http://hikarunakamura.com/) is his website which has the blog and twitter account which can hopefully guide you to what events he participated in the past as well as plans to.

Chess960 World League 2012 by Chess.com 
Team Armenia won this. [Here](http://www.chess.com/news/team-armenia-wins-chess960-wl2012-1894) is more information

Here is the [Chess960 World League 2013 Information](http://www.chess.com/groups/forumview/chess960-wl2013-divisions?lc=1)

Additionally searching [on Chessbase.com](http://www.chessbase.com/searchresult.asp) would yield more news of past championships. [chess960frc.blogspot.com](http://chess960frc.blogspot.com/) is a specific blog on Chess960.

Answer (score 0):

And now in 2021 obviously there's

FIDE World Fischer Random Chess Championship 2019

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_World_Fischer_Random_Chess_Championship_2019

Chess 9LX

https://www.uschesschamps.com/2020-champions-showdown-chess-9lx/overview